# Python String Problem with a map and lambda function

Tags: python, string, dictionary, lambda

I wrote a python function that should accept a string, and returns the same string with all even indexed characters in each word upper cased, and all odd indexed characters in each word lower cased. 
E.g.: to_weird_case('Weird string case') # => returns 'WeIrD StRiNg CaSe'

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    s = list(string.split(" "))
    words = []
    for word in s:
        w = map(lambda x: x.upper() if word.index(x)%2 == 0 else x.lower(), word)
        w = "".join(list(w))
        words.append(w)

    #print(words)
    return " ".join(words)
```

Now to my problem: As soon as more than one word is passed, the last letters of the last word are all converted to uppercase and I don't understand why... 
E.g.: to_weird_case('This is a testii') returns ThIs Is A TeSTII

Thanks for help

Comment: `word.index` doesn't find the index of the letter you're currently looking at, it finds the index of the ***first occurrence of that characters within the string…***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `index()` function returns the index of the first instance of that character in a string. What you want is to write your loop using enumerate:

`for index, word in enumerate(s):`

With this, rather than use the index function, you can write your logic based on the `index` variable passed from `enumerate()`.